# Permissions associated with a Model, then users with that Model get permissions (laravel-permission)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-permission

I have the following Models:

- Divisions
- Ranks
- Users

A division is assigned to a rank, and a rank can be assigned to a user.

Integrating the spatie/laravel-permission package for permissions, I'm unsure of the approach I need to take to make it so permissions can be assigned to a Division. Then, the users assigned to a rank in the division should have the added permissions given from the Division.

For example:
There is a division, Division A, with a rank called Rank 1. A user is given Rank 1. Division A is assigned the create_post and edit_post permission. The user would then have the create_post and edit_post permissions as they are a rank apart of a division with these assigned permissions.

Comment: Where do you need help? What have you done so far? Would you share some code?

Comment: @GreenPepper I have the relationships between the divisions and ranks, and ranks and users set up already, and have the spatie permissions package installed. Though, I have nothing related to the permissions setup as I have no clue at the approach I must take in order to translate a division's permissions to the user's permissions.

Comment: Ah, just to understand. You want to give the spatie permissions a divison and members inside this division should have equal rights?

Comment: Correct. Say, a division is given the read_article permission. All the users in that division should have that permission

Comment: @GreenPepper Sorry if it's a bit confusing, I'll try my best to clarify anything aha